# Django doesn't display database content

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have defined models and views. I would like to display **Project** existing from database. However script is not displaying any content. Where's the problem? Please take a look into definition of model, views and html template of file trying to display projects from database with use of *for* loop.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from bifrost.models import CustomUser

# Create your models here.

# Model Projektu
class Project(models.Model):
    PROJECT_TYPE = (
        ('SCR', 'Scrum'),
        ('KAN', 'Kanban'),
    )
    project_key = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PROJECT_TYPE, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateField(null=True)

# Definicja nazwy modelu w Adminie Django
    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Project

# Create your views here.

class ProjectListView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project-list.html'
    contect_object_name = 'projects_list'

def projectslist(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'project_list.html', {'projects': projects})
```

**project-list.html template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<h1 class="h3 mb-2 text-gray-800">{% block title %}Projects{% endblock title %}</h1>

{% block content %}

<!-- DataTales Example -->
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
    <div class="card-header py-3">
      <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">List of Projects</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Project Key</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Created</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <!-- <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Project Key</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Created</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot> -->
          <tbody>
                {% for project in projects_list %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ project.project_key }}</td>
              <td>{{ project.project_name }}</td>
              <td>{{ project.project_type }}</td>
              <td>{{ project.date_created }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>


{% endblock content %}
```

Debugger is not showing any issues. Pylint only show small suggestions, no errors as well.

Answer (score 1):

`{% for project in projects_list %}`

Change this row in your template because you passed projects as your key in context and you are using **projects_list**.

Try `{% for project in projects %}`

And it should work.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear and indeed you're right. However after updating for loop I still don't have results printed out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From your views file you are passing **projects** as a parameter like: `return render(request, 'project_list.html', {'projects': projects})`, and in templates files you are accessing it with **projects_list**, which will not return anything.

In you templates file replace:

`{% for project in projects_list %}`

with:

`{% for project in projects %}`

It will work.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear and indeed you're right. However after updating `for` loop I still don't have results printed out. Any ideas?

Comment: @yorgwarez Also, the endblock should be writtern as `{% endblock %}` instead `{% endblock content  %}`